# The meaning of "a stipple"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The definitions I found for this word was all art/drawing related.

> Oxford dictionary: (in drawing, painting, and engraving) mark (a surface) with numerous small dots or specks.
>
> Cambridge dictionary: to draw or paint something using small spots or
>   marks

Which doesn't seems to apply in this context.

> He’s wearing the uniform of the Guardians, but his cap is tilted at a
>   jaunty angle and his sleeves are rolled to the elbow, showing his
>   forearms, tanned but with **a stipple** of dark hairs.

Please provide me with a definition, thanks.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stipple) sense 3b': stipple
 ...
noun
3. 
a.  the art or method of painting, drawing, or engraving in dots [or marks, CED]
b.  the effect produced by this, or an effect, as in nature, resembling it

Comment: Currently, We would say "with a **stippling** of dark hairs. (If we said it at all...)

Answer (score 2):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/stipple) sense 3b' is the relevant one:

> **stipple** ... noun ...
>
> - 3a. the art or method of painting, drawing, or engraving in dots [or 'marks',
>     [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/stipple);
>     other dictionaries have 'flicks', 'flecks' or 'specks']
> - 3b. the effect produced by this, *or an effect, as in nature, resembling it*

[italicising mine]